# Mapping results of a JSON array response

Tags: api, json, apexrest

I have a JSON response object that contains an array, the array only ever contains one value. I want to map the result of to a field in a salesforce object.

I have a response class with an Array called State :

```
public class JobResponse{     
    public string uuid {get; set;}
    public datetime startedOn {get; set;}
    public string description {get; set;}
    public datetime completedOn {get; set;}
    public string jobId {get; set;}
    public JobLead jobLead {get; set;}
    public datetime scheduledOn {get; set;}
    public datetime createdOn {get; set;}
    public list <State> state {get; set;}
    public Signature signature {get; set;}
    public customField customFields {get; set;}
    public Location location {get; set;}
}
public class State {
    public string state{get; set;}
}
```

but i'm not sure how to map the result of the array to a field:

```
        JobResponse jobresp =  (JobResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), JobResponse.class);

     sc.FieldAwareId__c = jobresp.uuid;
     sc.FA_Job_ID__c = jobresp.jobId;
     sc.State__c = jobresp.State.state;
```

How would I map the jobresp.State.state response to a the sc.State__c field?

My example gives me an error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

Comment: you have to retrieve the 1st element from the list and then read the property..  sc.State__c = jobresp.State[0].state;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the response contains a list then you'll need to do something like:

```
List<JobResponse> jobresplist =  (List<JobResponse>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), List<JobResponse>.class);

JobResponse jobresp = jobresplist[0];
sc.FieldAwareId__c = jobresp.uuid;
sc.FA_Job_ID__c = jobresp.jobId;
sc.State__c = jobresp.State.state;
```

Comment: If the response doesn't tell you the amount of objects in the Array is there some way to count the objects to iterate through the array?

Comment: Yea definitely, you could use jobresplist.size() for example.